# Redux Store Issue

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

We have an app developed using react native and redux (using redux persist as well). I observe that when I uninstall the app and install the updated app (my app still picks up the old state values from redux) which is very strange.

My understanding is when I uninstall the app all the values in redux should be wiped off and when I install the new app it should start afresh isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check your initial state, when you are creating a reducer?

Comment: we don't have anything in the initial state..once the user logs in the login details are stored. Now the fun part is when I uninstall the app and install the app again the app picks up the values from the old app's state and shows that the user is already logged in..

Answer (score 0):

Some Android devices do that. I also faced this issue on some specific Android phones. Try testing it on some other device.

Comment: i see this on ios as well. another thing I observed is if i have the same app (with different bundle id) then also the values get picked from across the apps..really weird.